# How to modified sky mote or wake change wake up time periodically in contiki 2.7?

Tags: networking, iot, contiki, cooja

I am working on the Contiki 2.7 cooja simulator . I want to modified sky mote and I want to change periodically wake up time for each node manually ?

I check the hello.c and ipv6 sender c. file but I can not find any solution